# c++ static int in a class - compile time error

Tags: c++

I want to have a simple class i can call to get a unique number whilst the program is running - i can do the below with a dynamic allocation, and then just `delete` when not needed, but i still wanted to get a `static` version too.
Strangely, the code below (which is seemingly straightforward) throws some strange comiple errors (appended below).

Any ideas whats going on ? is this an incorrect use of static ?

```
class Id_gen {
    private:
 //adding static here stops the code from compiling:
 static int curr_id;

    public:

 Id_gen() {curr_id = 1; cout<<"debug:constructed"; }
 int get_id() {curr_id++; return curr_id; };
};

int main () {


    Id_gen bGen;
    cout << bGen.get_id() <<endl;

return 0;    
}
```

running g++ (linux 64):

```
c++2.cpp:(.text._ZN6Id_genC1Ev[Id_gen::Id_gen()]+0xe): undefined reference to `Id_gen::curr_id'
/tmp/cc766N6p.o: In function `Id_gen::get_id()':
c++2.cpp:(.text._ZN6Id_gen6get_idEv[Id_gen::get_id()]+0xa): undefined reference to `Id_gen::curr_id'
c++2.cpp:(.text._ZN6Id_gen6get_idEv[Id_gen::get_id()]+0x13): undefined reference to `Id_gen::curr_id'
c++2.cpp:(.text._ZN6Id_gen6get_idEv[Id_gen::get_id()]+0x19): undefined reference to `Id_gen::curr_id'
```

Comment: Those are link errors, not compile errors.

Comment: Those are linker errors, not compile time errors. The distinction matters - particularly once you start working in teams and are creating libraries for your colleagues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the initialization/definition of the static member as:

```
int Id_gen::curr_id = 0;
```

after the class definition.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comment by @sbi : Initialization is optional, the linker requires the definition only.

Comment: Initialization isn't important for the linker. It's the __definition__ the linker needs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to **define** the `static` variable outside the class as:

```
int Id_gen::curr_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the static member in a translation unit (cpp file):

```
int Id_Gen::curr_id = 0; // Initial value
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define the static instance variable in your class implementation, i.e.:

```
int Id_Gen::curr_id = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others you need to define the variable outside of the class:

```
int Id_Gen::curr_id;
```

If there is nothing else in this class you could omit the constructor and initialise this variable when you define it and make the `get_id()` function static too. This would allow you to call `Id_Gen::get_id()` without creating an instance of the class. In its current state if you mistakenly created two `Id_Gen`'s you would reset your id.